# Java - Trying to generate factorials

Tags: java, calculator

I'm making a calculator, and am adding a few more complicated buttons. The one I can't get my head around is factorial. I know what it is, but can't seem to make it. When I look at other people's questions, the code - for me anyway - doesn't work (Btw this is not a homework question). Here is the bit of code around where the algorithm (is that the word for it?) for the factorial:

```
} else if (oper.equals("shriek")) {

                resultm.setText("" + answer);
                resultl.setText("");
                resultr.setText("");
                oper = "";
                currentNuml = "";
                currentNumr = "";
            }
```

NB: The gap between

```
} else if (oper.equals("shriek")) {
```

and

```
resultm.setText("" + answer);
```

is where the algorithm would go.
Thanks, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, what have you tried? There are tons of implementations out there (all variants of two basic ones), where's your attempt at including one of them in your code?

Comment: I suggest splitting out the arithmetic from the display code. The place were you are trying to calculate factorial should have nothing to do with strings. Once you do that, a search for "java factorial" should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two variants for creating a factorial would be a recursive and non-recursive method.

The basic logic of a factorial is `5! = 5*4*3*2*1`

So that should be simple to implement with a loop (non-recursive). Just keep multiplying the number with the loop number to generate loop number

```
int fact(int no){
   int result=1;
   for (int i=1;i<no;i++)result*=i;
   return result;
}
```

The second is a recursive algorithm. This means calling the function from within itself.

```
int fact(int no){
   if(no==1)
           return 1;
   else
           return no * fact(no-1);
}
```

This will work like so.

For example fact(3)

```
no=3 Go to else return 3*fact(2)
    no=2 Go to else return 2* fact(1)
                 no=1 return 1
    no=2 return 2*1 => 2
no=3 Return 3*2 => 6
```

Hope this helped you understand

Comment: This I know, but how can I put that into the class? I've tried that kind of constructor between the two lines I mentioned, but it gave lots of errors (I had initialised all the variables). Would this be because I did this before I declared public static void main(String[]args) ?

Comment: constructor? These aren't constructors their methods. Did what before you declared psvm ? If your running these methods straight from the main method (psvm) add the static keyword to these methods (otherwise there'll be errors). There is a reason for that so I'd think you require some research

Comment: Yeah... I don't mean the constructor I mean the int fact(int no) { thing. I do need research in many areas! I'm no where near a polished java programmer, and I know it. I'm still doing tutorials on youtube to learn more - this I'm just doing on the side.